# Return partitioned row_num()=1 in same cte

Tags: postgresql

Is there a shorter way to filter a cte on rown_num = 1 rather than an external where clause? I vaguely recall doing this in teradata with a 'qualify' statement. Is there a less code way I can use in Postgres?

```
with 

first_touch as (
select 
    l.session_id as last_session,
    l.client_id,
    f.session_id as first_session,
    row_number() over(partition by f.client_id order by f.date asc) as rn 
from ga_marketing.sessions l
join ga_marketing.sessions f on l.client_id = f.client_id 
where l.date between '2021-06-01' and '2021-06-11'
)

select *
from first_touch
where rn = 1
```

I would rather somehow filter within the cte for rn=1 rather than outside. Is this possible? Is there a shorter way to write what I want?

Comment: Short answer: no. BTW: there is an extra `,` in your query (after the CTE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least two levels of select to do that with a Window function.  You could do both levels in the CTE if you wanted and then have a third dummy select outside the CTE, but I don't see what the point of that would be, other than to make the dummy select appear cleaner (no WHERE clause, no column "rn").  That part would get shorter, but the CTE would get longer.  Or you could just do away with the CTE altogether and write nested queries directly, which I guess would be "shorter" in the number keystrokes used.  Or you could encapsulate different fragments into a view, to hide some of the levels from sight.

I think you could also write this using DISTINCT ON or JOIN LATERAL, rather than using a window function, but that doesn't seem to be what you are asking.